# how to limit and clamp distance between two points in a Line renderer unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, limit, draw, distance, clamp

I am making a game which let you click on a ball and drag to draw a line renderer with two points and point it to a specific direction and when release I add force to the ball,
for now, I just want to know how can I limit the distance between those two points like give it a radius.

[image: You can take a look at here.]

Comment: Could you please post what you have implemented so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply clamp it using a [`Mathf.Min`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Min.html).

Since you didn't provide any example code unfortunately here is some example code I made up with a simple plane with a `MeshCollider`, a child object with the `LineRenderer` and a camera set to `Orthographic`. You probably would have to adopt it somehow.

```c#
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    // adjust in the inspector
    public float maxRadius = 2;

    private Vector3 startPosition;

    [SerializeField] private LineRenderer line;
    [SerializeField] private Collider collider;
    [SerializeField] private Camera camera;

    private void Awake()
    {
        line.positionCount = 0;

        line = GetComponentInChildren<LineRenderer>();
        collider = GetComponent<Collider>();
        camera = Camera.main;
    }

    // wherever you dragging starts
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        line.positionCount = 2;

        startPosition = collider.ClosestPoint(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z)));

        var positions = new[] { startPosition, startPosition };

        line.SetPositions(positions);
    }

    // while dragging
    private void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        var currentPosition = GetComponent<Collider>().ClosestPoint(camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, transform.position.z)));

        // get vector between positions
        var difference = currentPosition - startPosition;

        // normalize to only get a direction with magnitude = 1
        var direction = difference.normalized;

        // here you "clamp" use the smaller of either
        // the max radius or the magnitude of the difference vector
        var distance = Mathf.Min(maxRadius, difference.magnitude);


        // and finally apply the end position
        var endPosition = startPosition + direction * distance;

        line.SetPosition(1, endPosition);
    }
}
```

---

This is how it could look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've written the following pseudo code, which may help you

```
float rang ;

Bool drag=true; 
GameObject ball;

OnMouseDrag () { 
if(drag) { 
//Put your dragging code here

}

if (ball.transform.position>range)
     Drag=false;
else Drage=true;

}
```

Comment: doing this you will not be able to move the endpoint anywhere else after you reached the limit once. What if you want to move it back or change the direction after reaching the limit?