# How can i move game object to mouse position while in players range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I am trying to make weapon which is an orb. I tried almost everything but couldn't make weapon following mouse while in range of player. Can anyone help me?

Here is player hierarchy:
[Player Prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wfoI.png)

Here is my code. The problem in this code is maxDistance is always between 0-6. Max distance doesn't fit with player movement. If you have better solution to this it would be awesome to hear.

```
    public Transform weaponParent;
    public float maxMoveSpeed = 10;
    public float smoothTime = 0.3f;
    Vector2 currentVelocity;
    [SerializeField] private float maxDistance = 6f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        var target = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(mousePosition, maxDistance);

        weaponParent.position = Vector2.SmoothDamp(weaponParent.position, target, ref currentVelocity, smoothTime, maxMoveSpeed);

    }
```

Comment: Is this all the code? I don’t see how you are taking player position into consideration. Also you are clearly clamping the distance to 6 so what  do you expect it to be instead?

Comment: @ephb no there is also player movement scripts but i didn't post it since it's not neccesarry. I couldn't figure out how can I take player position into consideration. I was expecting the maximum distance of the weapon object from the player to be 6 while weapon parent follows mouse. If you have any idea about how can i do this let me know.

Comment: What @ephb tried to tell you is .. there is no reference to a player object anywhere in your code whatsoever.. so how do you want us to tell you how to take its position into account? For clamping to a maximum distance see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329885/7111561

Comment: @derHugo i get it now. Script is already player's component. Thanks for example i will try it. I tought best way to do it using clamp magnitude but it's not even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get your issue now

you are clamping a position (which is a vector starting at world (0,0,0), you rather want to clamp the vector between them like e.g.

```
var target = transform.position +  Vector2.ClampMagnitude(mousePosition - transform.position, maxDistance);
```